# C++ Constructor does not see the member of a member object

Tags: c++

I have met a strange case: I have an object that have some string members, that I use to initialize some other members like here:

```
class A
{
private:
   B b;
   C c1;
   C c2;

public:
   A(const string& str) : b(str), c1(b.foo1()), c2(b.foo2()) {}

// ...
};

class B
{
public:
   B(const string& str)
   { 
      // ... 
   }
   string& foo1()
   {
      string s1;
      // initialization
      return s1;
   }
   string& foo2()
   {
      string s2;
      // initialization
      return s2;
   }
};
class C
{
private:
   string s;
public:
   C(const string& str) : s(str) {}
};
```

When I call the constructor of A:

```
string str = "some string here";
A(str);
```

I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::replace
```

the problem is here:

```
A(const string& str) // str == "some string here"
   : b(str),         // enters the B(str), str == "some string here"
     c1(b.foo1()),   // enters the C(str), str the string that I want
     c2(b.foo2())    // enters the C(str), but str is not visible
```

- I do not know what is happening.
- Is member `A::b` out of scope?
- it does not matter if I use `foo1()` or `foo2()` for initializing c2, the problem is the same

How would you suggest me to do it?

Comment: Members are initialized in the order they appear *in the class declaration*. Make sure that `b` is initialized before it is used.

Comment: It is, that is why I wrote it like this. More, I  have said that c1 is initialized well

Comment: `foo1` can't return a reference to a local.

Comment: Well, it seems that it works like this, and it works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a local variable in `foo1` and `foo2`(`s1` and `s2` respectively) this is not allowed and using the reference will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon undefined behavior is just what you expect - undefined. It may work out of a miracle and may fail some other time. You should **never** write code invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: ok, but what is the solution? how should i return the string?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon return the string **by copy**. Simply remove the ampersand(`&`) in both `foo1` and `foo2` like so: `string foo1()` note the lack of `&`.

Comment: isn't this slow? returning object instead of its address (or pointer)

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon well the object has to live somewhere. In `c++11` you can make use of the move semantic but in pre-c++11 there is no such thing. You could allocate some object on the heap and return a pointer to it, but then someone will have to take care to free it.

Comment: So you are saying that my older problem of returning objects is solved starting with c++11 ? Is c++ getting closer to Java in this way?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon this is off topic for the question being asked. Please avoid adding such comments. There is plenty of information online for c++11. The question at hand was why the code is failing and I believe my answer helps with that.

Comment: My question is "How would you suggest me to do?(so it would run fast, obviously)" ... and in your comments you suggested me to remove the reference. I am not very confident with it for now, but I will study the fact

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50694/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-thedarkside-ofthemoon)

Answer (score 2):

You are returning references to local variables in both foo1 and foo2. These variable are limited in scope to the body of the functions in which they are defined. They disappear as soon as the function returns, so attempts to reference them after this cause your program to crash.

Comment: my question is how would you suggest me to do?